# Joomla: Move article text to another position

Tags: php, joomla

I am changing a little bit protostar template and I would like to show article text no at content possition but on sidebar.

I have found that text is shown by this
components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php
line 111:

```
<?php echo $this->item->text; ?>
```

but when I put this somewhere in `templates\protostar\index.php` it does not work (as expected :))

Could you please advice how to move this?

Thanks!

Comment: That is from the article layout not the index file ... the index file is for everything not just articles.  If you want to move the location of the component text then you need to move the jdoc::include tag for component to where you want that. But you might want to actually copy protostar and make a new index.php so that the change doesn't change everything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do changes in your `templates\protostar\index.php` file where :

*Cut*

```
<jdoc:include type="message" />
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

from this code :

```
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <?php if ($this->countModules('position-8')) : ?>
    <!-- Begin Sidebar -->
         <div id="sidebar" class="span3">
            <div class="sidebar-nav">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-8" style="xhtml" />
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- End Sidebar -->
   <?php endif; ?>
   <main id="content" role="main" class="<?php echo $span; ?>">
    <!-- Begin Content -->
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-3" style="xhtml" />

            <jdoc:include type="message" />
            <jdoc:include type="component" />

            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-2" style="none" />
                        <!-- End Content -->
    </main>
    <?php if ($this->countModules('position-7')) : ?>
        <div id="aside" class="span3">
        <!-- Begin Right Sidebar -->
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-7" style="well" />
        <!-- End Right Sidebar -->
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
```

and *paste* it **after position-7 or before postion-3**, whichever side you need to show your content, i.e.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <?php if ($this->countModules('position-8')) : ?>
     <!-- Begin Sidebar -->
     <div id="sidebar" class="span3">
       <div class="sidebar-nav">
          <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-8" style="xhtml" />
       </div>
     </div>
     <!-- End Sidebar -->
   <?php endif; ?>
   <main id="content" role="main" class="<?php echo $span; ?>">
    <!-- Begin Content -->
       <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-3" style="xhtml" />
       <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-2" style="none" />
    <!-- End Content -->
   </main>
   <?php if ($this->countModules('position-7')) : ?>
      <div id="aside" class="span3">
        <!-- Begin Right Sidebar -->

          <jdoc:include type="message" />
          <jdoc:include type="component" />

          <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-7" style="well" />
         <!-- End Right Sidebar -->
       </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this tip, unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. This move entire article including article image, heading etc.  to another position. I just need to move "content" (text) of the article....